# Grails: What is to set in the controller in order to reach the error handling in the URL mapping?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Using Grails 2.3.9

In the controller I'm trying to make a request go through the error handling declared in the URL mappings. I've read the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.9/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToResponseCodes), but I still don't get how this works.

From the example of the documentation:

```
static mappings = {
   "403"(controller: "errors", action: "forbidden")
   "404"(controller: "errors", action: "notFound")
   "500"(controller: "errors", action: "serverError")
}
```

For example in a controller:

```
def update() {
    // do some tests
    if(forbidden) {
        // Go to 403
        //response.status = response.SC_FORBIDDEN
        render status: 403 
        return
    }
    // deal with normal case
}
```

What do I have to do in the controller in order to land on the 403 action? Doing `response.status = response.SC_FORBIDDEN` or `render status: 403` is not working.

I was able to achieve going through mappings 403 by throwing a custom exception ForbiddenException while the url mappings would contain:

```
"403"(controller: "errors", action: "forbidden", exception: ForbiddenException)
```

However, I guess, reaching the error controller through another controller should also go with throwing an exception for each case, no?

Comment: how about :response.sendError 403

Comment: @vahid: Thanks. This, however, gives me a 404 (whatever the error code) with a default response (not declared in url mappings).

Comment: response.status = 403
 render "some response"  should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429388/how-can-i-return-a-404-50x-status-code-from-a-grails-controller

Comment: `response.sendError 403` works perfectly. Make sure you have created controller and action as in your URL mapping and rendered something from action.

Comment: Thanks both, vahid and user1690588, for reconfirming that this is the way. I left the exception, when I tried the "sendError". Does anyone of you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: vahid should post it as answer as he is the first.

Comment: OK may be vahid is not interested. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
response.sendError 403
```

and make sure you have created controller and action as in your URL mapping and rendered something from action.